# Initializing a struct in C : initializer element is not constant

Tags: c, struct, initialization

I have read other answers on this topic, but they didn't help me.
I am trying to initalize a struct but getting the following error msgs in C:

**error: initializer element is not constant**

**error: (near initialization for 'resource01.resource.role')**

For Url it works, it's just the role which is not working. And if I'm defining the role as char, I don't have any problems. What am I doing wrong?

```
static char const resource01Url[] = "/dummy";
static int const resource01Role = 2;
static struct RestResourceNode_S resource01 =
{
    {
        resource01Url,
        resource01Role,
        &DummyHandler_call
    },
    NULL
};

static struct RestResourcesManager_S resourcesManager =
{
    &resource01, &resource01
};
```

The type RestResourceNode_S is defined:

```
struct RestResourceNode_S
{
    RestResource_T resource;
    struct RestResourceNode_S const *next;
}
```

and RestResource_t:

```
struct RestResource_S
{
    char const *url;

    int const *role;

    retcode_t (*handle)(Msg_T *);
};

typedef struct RestResource_S RestResource_T;
```

Comment: First, you're assigning an `int const *` member a value that is `int const`. Either change `role` to be `int const` or change the initializer to be `&resource01Role`

Comment: and what does the `DummyHandler_call` function prototype look like?

Comment: The Dummy function doesn't work with the resource... I don't think that the error is there...

Comment: Then I think the error @WhozCraig pointed out is the only one.

Comment: Yes, that was the error :D Could you explain me why it was that way?

Comment: How can I access now the value of the variable role?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error means that you are using a non-constant expression to initialize a structure member.

The expression is `resource01Role`.

While it is declared as `static` and `const` it is not an *initializer constant expression* from the view of the C compiler. If you want to use it this way, you would have to define it as a preprocessor macro. In your case, `const` only points out to the compiler that the value of `resource01Role` will not change - it does not permit it to use the value during compile-time.

However, as @WhozCraig pointed out, the type of role is actually `int const *`, so you probably meant to write `&resource01Role`. Adress-of *is* a constant expression, so that would compile.

Since `resource01Url` is an array, the adress-of operator `&` is implicitly applied by the compiler, so it is constant.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you tell me why it works for url and for role it doesn't work?

Comment: How can I access now the value of the variable role?

Comment: @user3464679 Edited answer to explain that char[] gets an implicit &. I'm not sure I understand your second question - `resource01.resource.role` will give you the pointer and `*(resource01.resource.role)` the value it points to.